# What's the entropy change in quantum teleportation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-teleportation

Suppose a single qubit quantum teleportation From A to B through a bell states by quantum gate performance.

The setting was the usual one usual one i.e.
Suppose initial the unknown states $|\psi\rangle=a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle$, and that $A$ and $B$ did not know anything about the states, and $A$ perform the operation of $|\psi\rangle$ with $|\Phi^+\rangle$.

I'm interested in the entropy of the states.

My professor told me that, since the quantum gate operation were all unitary operation, the entropy in the system should not increase.

However, for some reason I don't feel right about it.

For example, let $a=b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, the initial states has four bases, and after the operation by $A$ and before $A$ made the measurement, there's $8$ basis in the system.

Simple calculation through Von Neumann entropy indicated a change in the entropy.

```
-(1/2)^2*log((1/2)^2) *4
1.3862943611198906
-(1/2*1/sqrt(2))^2*log( (1/2*1/sqrt(2))^2  ) *8
2.0794415416798357
```

This seemed to indicate that: the fact that $A$ and $B$ knows their states to be entangled somehow made the unitary gate operation non-unitary in terms of entropy through entanglement.

I also found a paper seemed to be describing exactly this question(https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1227), but it's confusing of where they were getting at.

Could you help me to understand what exactly was going on with the total entropy in $A$ and $B$?

Does it increase/change or not?
(I'm using Von Neumann Entropy here, but I'm not sure if it's a suitable choice.)

Comment: Unitary gates? There is a measurement!  But I'm not sure what you are really asking. Can you try to clarify?  Entropy of what?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Entropy of the total system in space $AB$.

Comment: Well, this is certainly the same at the beginning and the end of the teleportation protocol.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Not really, after the measurement, the probability is only from Bob's $a$ and $b$, but before everything, there's contribution from the bell states as well?